# Recursion in depth (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, return

Check the following code:

```
>>> def fib(x):
...    if x == 0 or x == 1:
...        return 1
...    else: 
...        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
>>> print(fib(4))
```

According to the comments in the SoloLearn Python tutorial (for Recursion), the code works like this:

```
1. fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2)
2. = (fib(2) + fib(1)) + (fib(1) + fib(0))
3. = fib(1) + fib(0) + fib(1) + fib(1) + fib(0)
4. = 1+ 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
5. = 5
```

After line 2, only `fib(2)` should go the else part of the `fib()` function, right?
The two `fib(1)` and the single `fib(0)` meet the criteria of the if part of the `fib()` function. So 1 is returned. My question is, why in the 3rd line, `fib(1) + fib(0) + fib(1) + fib(1) + fib(0)` are all replaced by 1's and then added?

Do forgive me for asking such a noob question.

Comment: Because all of those calls resolve to the first clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a double recursive function, so its call result a tree structure of calls with the base case of fib(1) and fib(0)

```
fib(4) =                  fib(3)          +        fib(2)    
                         /      \                 /     \
fib(4) =        (  fib(2)   +    fib(1) ) + ( fib(1) + fib(0) )    
                  /     \         |              |        |
fib(4) = ( ( fib(1) + fib(0) ) + fib(1) ) + ( fib(1) + fib(0) )    
               |        |          |            |        |
fib(4) = ( (   1    +   1    ) +   1    ) + (   1    +   1    )    
                  \   /            |               \    /
fib(4) = ( (        2        ) +   1    ) + (        2        )    
                        \       /                    |
fib(4) = (                  3           ) + (        2        )    
                                   \             /
fib(4) =                                  5
```

you can also visualize the working of the function by adding some prints in the right places and a extra auxiliary argument to aid with it and some other minor changes

```
>>> def fib(n, nivel=0):
        if n==0 or n==1:
            print(" "*nivel,"fib(",n,")=1")
            return 1
        else:
            print(" "*nivel,"fib(",n,")")
            result = fib(n-1,nivel+1) + fib(n-2,nivel+1)
            print(" "*nivel,"fib(",n,")=",result)
            return result

>>> fib(4)
 fib( 4 )
  fib( 3 )
   fib( 2 )
    fib( 1 )=1
    fib( 0 )=1
   fib( 2 )= 2
   fib( 1 )=1
  fib( 3 )= 3
  fib( 2 )
   fib( 1 )=1
   fib( 0 )=1
  fib( 2 )= 2
 fib( 4 )= 5
5
>>>
```

here you can notice that the call are resolved in sequence from left to right and bottom up

Answer (score 3):

I believe the description of how the code works is misleading, since it seems to show that not every values are evaluated when going from one line to the next. If we replace everything by the functions it calls (or the value it returns) on the next line, and put parentheses like on your example, we get the following, that might help you understand better the inner workings of that code :

```
1. fib(4) 
2. = fib(3) + fib(2)
3. = (fib(2) + fib(1)) + (fib(1) + fib(0))
4. = ((fib(1) + fib(0)) + 1) + (1 + 1)
5. = 1 + 1 + 1 + 2
6. = 5
```

Comment: Why is fib(1) from line 3 replaced by 1 in line 4?

Comment: Still not a fan of this description, because to me it implies some sort of parallelization.  The reality is that one of the calls on line 2 is plumbed to its depths first, before the next one is ever considered.

Comment: @Ahnaf Because if the `if` clause in your recursion!  See Robert Columbia's answer, and note that when you call `fib(1)` the value of argument `x` is 1.

Answer (score 2):

@MorganThrapp is correct. More specifically, the base case of the recursive function `fib` is:

```
if x==0 or x==1:
    return 1
```

This clause is triggered when `fib(1)` or `fib(0)` is called. In programming parlance, the function *evaluates* to its return value, which here is `1`.

In your example of `fib(4)`, `fib` gets called five times with either a `1` or a `0` input and those results are all added together, and that results in your final return value of `5` which is returned from your original call to `fib(4)` and immediately passed into the `print` function.